# grep/pdfgrep perl regex to check multiple lines

Tags: regex, grep

I want to check if in my text exists different words. This words are in the complete text. But I don't find a regex for grep/pdfgrep with perl regex.

```
My text with foo with other text and
many many
other lines
in the same text
for bar and i don't know
```

My regex for pdfgrep (same as grep)

```
pdfgrep -i -P "foo.*bar" mypdf.pdf
```

This don't work, because the words are on different lines. I have try many other regex as .* where I found for other regex:

```
(?s).*
([\s\S]*)
(.*?)
```

And many other. Givs a solution for grep/pdfgrep to find this?

I will check if my pdf File has insert all of the search words

EDIT: For me Now works this commands. Thank you to Pierre François

```
# Find foo AND bar
pdftotext mypdf.pdf - | tr '\n' ' ' | grep -P 'foo.*?bar'
# Find foo OR bar
pdftotext mypdf.pdf - | tr '\n' ' ' | grep -P 'foo|bar'
# The same Commands but with pdfgrep
# Find foo AND bar
pdfgrep -i -P ".*" mypdf.pdf | tr '\n' ' ' | grep -P 'foo.*?bar'
# Find foo OR bar
pdfgrep -i -P ".*" mypdf.pdf | tr '\n' ' ' | grep -P 'foo|bar'
```

The coimmand with sed works, But only find foo OR bar and not foo AND bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have **pdftotext** installed, you can use other methods than **grep** to get a regular expression acting across multiple lines. Try:

```
pdftotext mypdf.pdf - | sed -e '/foo/,/bar/p' -e d
```

The first command extracts a text from a PDF file to the standard output stream and the second one prints all the lines starting from one containing `foo` to another containing `bar`, and deletes all the other lines from the output.

**Edit**

Another solution with **pdftotext**, **tr** and **grep** is the following one:

```
pdftotext mypdf.pdf - | tr '\n' ' ' | grep -P 'foo.*?bar'
```

The command **tr** is used here to change every newline char into a space. I used the non greedy modifier `?` in the *regex* of **grep**, which is only available with the *-P* option for the case you have to match separately multiple occurences of the same string.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't get an output for this command. The pdftotext generate the txt file that works, but I think the sed is the problem?

Comment: The command pdftotext generates a txt file only if its second parameter is missing. Putting a `-` as second parameter sends its output to the standard output stream which is the input of sed. Is that your problem?

Comment: Thank you for help. The command with sed don't work for me. I think the Problem was that this use OR for foo and bar and not AND. The tr with grep work well. I have try .*? and | for OR and both works. Thank you. Is pdftotext faster? The tr wit grep can I allready use with PDFgrep (i have edit the first post